# SSH.NET SocketException: 10004 A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

Tags: c#, wpf, ssh-tunnel, ssh.net

I use SSH.NET to create SSH Tunnels in .Net-Applications. In a ConsoleApplication / Windows-Service of mine this library works just as expected.

Now I coded a WPF Application that creates an SSH-Tunnel to remotly access a MySQL Database.
I can access the database and execute my SQL Statements just fine.

But if I try to close the tunnel after disconnecting from the database i first get an SocketException: 10004 A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
an then several more Exceptions:

- SocketException: 10053 An established connection was stopped by the software in your host computer, possibly because of a data transmission time-out or protocol error.
- Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: Bad packet length XXX  (XXX is an random integer)
- Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: Client not connected.

I use following Code for opening / closing the tunnel:

```cs
public class SSHTunnelBuilder
{
    private SshClient client;
    private ForwardedPort port;

    public SSHTunnelBuilder()
    {
    }

    public void CloseTunnel()
    {
        if (this.port != null && this.port.IsStarted)
        {
            this.port.Stop();
        }

        if (this.client != null && this.client.ForwardedPorts.Contains(this.port))
        {
            this.client.RemoveForwardedPort(this.port);
        }

        this.port = null;

        if (this.client != null)
        {
            if (this.client.IsConnected)
            {
                this.client.Disconnect();
            }

            this.client.Dispose();
            this.client = null;
        }
    }

    public void OpenTunnel()
    {
        if (this.client == null)
        {
            this.client = new SshClient("host", "usr", "pwd");
        }

        if (!this.client.IsConnected)
        {
            this.client.Connect();
        }

        if (this.port == null)
        {
            this.port = new ForwardedPortLocal("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 10000, "YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY", 3306);
        }

        if (!this.client.ForwardedPorts.Contains(this.port))
        {
            this.client.AddForwardedPort(this.port);
        }

        if (!this.port.IsStarted)
        {
            this.port.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

And the SSHTunnelBuilder is used inside a TASK like this:

```cs
private void SomeMethod()
{  
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        new Action(() =>
        {

            SSHTunnelBuilder ssh = new SSHTunnelBuilder();
            try
            {

                ssh.OpenTunnel();

                // Do something

                ssh.CloseTunnel();
                ssh.Dispose();
                ssh = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                ssh.CloseTunnel();
                ssh.Dispose();
                ssh = null;
            }
        }));
}
```

**Can Somebody explain to me how to get rid of those Exceptions?**

Comment: Obvious question: what is different in how you work with SSH tunnels in your console application and in your WPF application? Consider it.

Comment: I tried to figure that out already. Without success. In both Applications i communicate with the same MySQL Server and even use the same statements on the same tables. The service runs an automated database sync every hour. The WPF-Desktop-App is used for viewing and editing. I use the same SSHTunnelBuilder-Class in both apps

Comment: I also tried a synchronous-version of SomeMethod() without the Task, so that the ssh reference would exist inside the UI-Thread. --> no change

Comment: Then you don't really close the database. Try to find out what is issuing that blocking operation that the socket exception complains about.